# jQuery + Full Page + Mobile Menu closing =Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, touch, fullpage.js

i've stumbled into a problem where I am not unable to close my mobile navigation menu.

I am using [jQuery Full Page](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjgl6zjyIXUAhXK1xQKHUPBCX8QFggwMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Falvarotrigo%2FfullPage.js%2F&usg=AFQjCNHlUDO3vz4HSxuzjaxl1gkWuLRpGw&sig2=iinaW6mbQ9gadUF55A1UKA) for my front-end. My mobile menu opens when clicked on:

```
<nav class="menu col-xs-4 pull-right">
  <a href="#">
    <span>Menu</span>
    <button>
      <span>toggle menu</span>
    </button>
  </a>
</nav>
```

With jQuery code of:

```
$('nav, .mobile-menu--close').click(function(e){
    $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
});
```

But it does nothing on closing with .mobile-menu--close

```
<a href="#" class="mobile-menu--close">
  <span>Close</span>
  <span class="mobile-menu--close-x"></span>
</a>
```

It is inside an aside element which is outside of main

```
    ...        
    <div class="background-image landing-mantas col-xs-8 pull-right">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <aside class="mobile-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Homepage</a>
      </li>
      <li>...
```

With mobile-open class it translates  X 100% and brings aside.mobile-menu from X100% to 0%. So basically it swaps these with positions.

I've read answers with disabling touch-actions: none and so on. Nothing does seem to help.

Full preview of web could be found [here](http://mantasmilka.com/stack/)

Keep in mind that this is wop so please view it in responsive view to get the point. But it should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this style and try

```
   .mobile-menu {
         z-index: -1; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the joob. Always these small stupid mistakes.

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the link you provided. When menu-open is applied then your navigation is not clickable, so you need to set `z-index` of menu-open to higher that the `z-index` of your content (I am assuming the the page is inside the content class) -

```
.menu-open{
 z-index: 1111;
}
.content{
z-index: 1000;
}
```